# What chages and adjustments to Chrome/Chromium are most effective to lower the number of writes and prolong the life of SSDs?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, google-chrome, firefox, ssd

I've got a Corsair Force 80 SSD, an AMD APU and 4 gigs of RAM as assets as well as some thumb drives I suppose. I'm running Mint Linux 17.1 64 bit in this box and mostly it's used to crawl the web. Lots of flash based video and chatrooms and Facebook photos live streaming video and etc required of it. (I do volunteer work for a non profit doing educational stuff, not that it matters for my question.) I use Chromium and Firefox browsers except on Facebook where Firefox no longer displays video to 64 bit Linux computers.

I just installed the new operating system alone on the aging SSD a few days ago and did a SMART drive test. Sure enough in a lot of places the SSD is warning that it is old and or has a few misreads etc that seem to point more towards a Corsair's eventual death than its immortality.

So, since my time is limitless and my cash is non existant what are the best practices and tactics I can use to make my browsers as nice as practicable to my poor old hard drive? If I had to pick between speed browsing and wear, and I probably will, I would say 70% of resources towards durability and 30% towards speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All following recommendations are given assuming you're the only user of the PC. If it's not the case, make sure to set up appropriate filesystem permissions on tmpfs in same place you'll create directories.

There are *chrome cache directories* under `~/.config/google-chrome/Default`. On Windows, these dirs are `Cache`, `Media Cache`, `IndexedDB` and `GPUCache`. Not sure about Linux, but something very similar (I have no Linux box with Chrome at hand to check). Depending on distibutive, Chrome main cache may be in `~/.cache/google-chrome`.

// if you're using Chromium instead of Chrome, dir is `~/.config/chromium/Default` and `~/.cache/chromium` [[ref]](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)

1. Make sure you've got another browser as a backup in case you mess up.
2. Add to your startup script (depending on distro and shell) creation of *Chrome cache directories* (listed above) under `/dev/shm/chrome-caches`. How to run script after login it is explained in [Q#10797150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797150/how-to-run-a-script-after-user-login-authentication-in-linux). Use `mkpdir -p` to create full paths.
3. reboot or once create manually `/dev/shm/chrome-caches`, close (and kill if it won't exit) Chrome, and them `mv` Chrome caches (listed above) to `/dev/shm/chrome-caches`
4. link them back as symlinks: `ln -s /dev/shm/chrome-caches/* ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/`
5. You can use Chrome right away, but be watchful after reboot, make sure Chrome can access its cache directories (launch it and check that they're not empty). In worst case, you can delete symlinks and Chrome will start will clean cache.

Note though that this will effectively clear Chrome cache and some sites meant-to-be-persistent-data every boot (though not offline google docs, which are in `Application Cache`, not cookies/history/bookmarks, which will stay intact, and not sync state).

Comment: This is something i should have mentioned. I already have put Firefox's cache into temfs lockdown and had prepared to do the same to Chromium (did the backups of the conf files I was going to change etc) Then I thought, that while putting cache in temfs might help out the hard drive some, and might speed up some browsers in some situations, it was seemingly a drop in the bucket of remaining writes in the hard drive. Then before I put more in Ram I came here to ask for advice. Thank you for yours

Comment: on some linux distributives, there are `~/.cache` directory with many seemingly not-required-to-be-kept-on-reboot data. Maybe there's reason to link it whole to `/dev/shm`. Though when I experimented with it, I found some programs complain when they can't find their cache directory (so you'll have to create these dirs for them).

Comment: I am the only user. Also persistence of browser cache is not extra important because they both synch the very important bookmarks and passwords etc. The correct use of flags and calls and awkward patches to get data where it belongs doesnt scare me, even though it should. That makes me the most dangerous man in the world to my own hard drive. Broken files and crippled programs can be fixed. Probably. with enough coffee and scratch paper for logic If I accidentally send the drive into a loop of reads over writes I might kill it with kindness

Comment: I am not sure how to say someones answer would answer my question. There probably isnt one lonesome answer to it. I am hoping for different ways different people might try in my shoes and I will try the codes, strategies, or ways of looking at it that I feel would best transfer when Im the one deciding whether or not to, as an example, let Ram make one root decision during boot before I can be there to help-:)

Comment: I've seen another idea wild, though didn't implement it myself.
As you've got bunch of USB flash disks, you can mount whole system root via OverlayFS (or unionfs) with read-only branch at original root and rw branch on external flash. This way, SDD will be used as fast read-only storage, and won't get writes until branches are merged. Here is more detailed explanation: http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs2/shwh/README.txt